# CSV Headers in Gmail, Yahoo, Outlook and Hotmail?

Tags: csv, outlook, gmail, contacts, hotmail

I want to know the list of CSV headers from the CSV files provided by GMail, Yahoo , Outlook and Hotmail. Tried looking over the internet for the list but couldn't find any.

I am trying to import the contact list from a given CSV file and need to make few operations on specific headers (example - name, first name , last name and phone number). The column index varies across CSVs.

Answer (score 0):

I was just about to do the same thing.
The obvious answer is to export from each account and see what headers they give :)

Comment: I have done the same way. In few cases the headers are different for the same type of CSV file (the file exported from gmail as an outlook csv file is different from the one exported from outlook)